# Есть ли способ в с++ лочить данные отдельно на запись и чтение?

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Я бы хотел сделать так, чтоб во время чтения данных блокировать возможность только записи, а во время записи блокировать возможность записи и
чтения, возможно ли сделать так в с++?

Comment: Какие-то чудеса вы хотите. Очень похоже на молоточек https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy

В C++ можно управлять барьерами памяти, но это не совсем то что вы хотите.

Судя по вашим прошлым вопросам, вы хотите сами изобрести Lock-Free Map?

Comment: В С++ нет вообще никаких способов как-то лочить данные на запись и чтение, ни вместе, не порознь. Конечно можно подобрать подходящую функцию из ОС, но оверхед будет чудовищным.

Comment: похоже кому то просто нужен std::shared_mutex или его аналог в виде RWLock

Comment: Создать два мьютекса. Один использовать для блокировки чтения, второй для блокировки чтения и записи. Принципиальных отличий между такими мьютексами нет. Всё различия вносите ВЫ, кода программируете логику использования мьютексов.

Comment: два вложенных мютекса не сделают RWLock, иначе зачем он существует. Если не верит, просто представьте себе, что операция чтения и записи не моментальная (то есть не 4 байта скопировать), а длинная (пару килобайт). В этом случае пока предыдущий читатель  ещё читает, входящий писатель уже может начать портить данные.

Comment: Вероятно, вы имеете ввиду std::shared_mutex https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex